# Regex: The word has maximum 30 characters but closest to 30 characters before it

Tags: regex

I need a regex to express "The word has maximum 30 characters but closest to 30 characters before it".

For example, suppose i have the following sentence:

```
It is a dark time for the Rebellion. Although the
```

The result of the expression should return "Rebellion".

Currently I use the expression:

```
(?<=.{30})\b\w+\b
```

But this will return "Although".
Anybody can help me get out of this? Many Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like this,

```
^.{1,30}\b(\w+)
```

By using the word boundary `\b`, regex engine  backtracks (in-order to find a word boundary within 1 to 30 chars) and then it tries to match a word boundary and also the following one or more word chars.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/tL8mE0/1)

**OR**

```
^.{1,30}\K\b\w+
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/tL8mE0/2)